# Trying to dual boot Ubuntu but windows disk management is only letting me shrink my main drive the right amount

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I have recently been looking at getting Ubuntu as some of my friends use it and reccomened it so I'm thinking I'll dual boot with windows to see how I like it. The problem is when I try to use the Disk Management app on windows to shrink my main drive and let me install Ubuntu it is only letting me shrink it by 11,699 MB even though it has 74,970 MB free.

It shows my disk being split up into 4 sections - Healthy (EFI System Partition), Windows (C:), Healthy (Recovery Partition) and Healthy (Recovery partition). The 74,970 MB free number that I mentioned before is just what comes up for the Windows (C:) drive as shown in this image - [74.97GB free space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdsPB.png). When I try and shrink this drive I get told that I can only shrink it by 11,699 MB as I said before [(as shown here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANG8v.png). I have run the windows optimize and defrag tool after seeing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K98dp.png) text but that doesn't seem to have helped.

Does anyone know why this might be happening or have a good tutorial that could walk me through it better? Also if you need more information please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe an immovable file, like the pagefile, which you need to turn off, remove, then shrink the partition, and restore the pagefile.  Not an Ubuntu problem, so a Windows forum would be a better place to see why shrinking does not work for you.

Comment: @ubfan1 Thanks! I might post it on the windows one then and try to find out what some common files like that might be. I did do an actual boot onto a USB stick (not a persistent live one) so I'm going to use that for now.